# Using Google Visualization, why is DataView content showing in ChartRangeFilter but not in its associated LineChart?

Tags: javascript, linechart, google-visualization

The code below should populate a DataView from a CSV file. The DataView is then fed to a DashBoard which inludes a LineChart and a ChartRangeFilter bound together. My problem is that while the ChartRangeFilter shows a proper chart preview and allows me to select the range the LineChart shows only an empty data set but with the right data type and axis labels. My assumption is that the DataView content is OK since the ChartRangeFilter is capable of showing it. Why then can't the LineChart do the same?

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['controls', 'charteditor']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    // Create CSV string
    csvString = 'TIME,TEMP0,HUM0\n13:00:04,24.7,50\n13:01:05,26.7,60\n13:02:04,22.7,52\n13:03:05,14.7,40\n13:04:04,34.7,80\n13:05:05,24.7,50';

    // Parse string into an Array
    var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});

    // Convert Array into a DataTable
    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);

    // Create DataView from DataTable
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

    // Convert string times in first column to timeofday (thanks to WhiteHat!)
    var columns = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
        columns.push(i);
    }

    columns[0] = {
        calc: function(dt, row) {
            var thisDate = new Date('1/1/2016 ' + dt.getValue(row, 0));
            return [thisDate.getHours(), thisDate.getMinutes(), thisDate.getSeconds(), thisDate.getMilliseconds()];
        },
        label: arrayData[0][0],
        type: 'timeofday'
    };

    // Determine which columns should be visible
    view.setColumns(columns);    

    // Create Dashboard
    var dash = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));

    // Range filter control wrapper
    var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
        containerId: 'control_div',
        options: {
            filterColumnIndex: 0,
            ui: {
                chartOptions: {
                    height: 50,
                    width: 1000,
                },
                chartView: {
                    columns: [0, 1,2]
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // Line chart wrapper
    var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: 'LineChart',
        containerId: 'chart_div',
        dataTable: view,
        options:{
            title: 'Home Automation - Environment Sensor Log',
            width: 1000,
            height: 400
        }   
    });

    // Bind control and chart in Dashboard
    dash.bind([control], [chart]);

    // Draw dashboard using Dataview as source
    dash.draw(view);
}
```

This is the current end result:

[image: LineChart not showing DataView content while ChartRangeFilter does]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tried a number of things to get the chart to work with `'timeofday'`, but no luck

however, using a `'date'` column, formatted as `'HH:mm:ss'` seems to work fine

see following working snippet.

changes include:

1) using `loader.js` vs. `jsapi`
2) changed `calc` function to return date formatted as time
3) added `hAxis.ticks` to both `chart` and `control`
4) used `getColumnRange` to set the `vAxis.viewWindow` on the `chart`

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    // Create CSV string
    csvString = 'TIME,TEMP0,HUM0\n13:00:04,24.7,50\n13:01:05,26.7,60\n13:02:04,22.7,52\n13:03:05,14.7,40\n13:04:04,34.7,80\n13:05:05,24.7,50';

    // Parse string into an Array
    var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});

    // Convert Array into a DataTable
    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);

    // Create DataView from DataTable
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

    // Convert string times in first column to timeofday (thanks to WhiteHat!)
    var columns = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
        columns.push(i);
    }

    var formatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern: 'HH:mm:ss'});
    columns[0] = {
        calc: function(dt, row) {
            var dateValue = new Date('1/1/2016 ' + dt.getValue(row, 0));
            return {
              v: dateValue,
              f: formatter.formatValue(dateValue)
            };
        },
        label: arrayData[0][0],
        type: 'date'
    };

    // Determine which columns should be visible
    view.setColumns(columns);

    var tickMarks = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < view.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
      tickMarks.push(view.getValue(i, 0));
    }

    // Create Dashboard
    var dash = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));

    // Get column range min & max
    var yRange1 = view.getColumnRange(1);
    var yRange2 = view.getColumnRange(2);

    var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
        containerId: 'control_div',
        options: {
            filterColumnIndex: 0,
            ui: {
                chartOptions: {
                    height: 50,
                    width: 1000,
                    hAxis: {
                      ticks: tickMarks,
                      format: 'HH:mm:ss'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // Line chart wrapper
    var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: 'LineChart',
        containerId: 'chart_div',
        options:{
            pointSize: 8,
            title: 'Home Automation - Environment Sensor Log',
            width: 1000,
            height: 400,
            hAxis: {
              ticks: tickMarks,
              format: 'HH:mm:ss'
            },
            vAxis: {
              viewWindow: {
                min: Math.min(yRange1.min, yRange2.min),
                max: Math.max(yRange1.max, yRange2.max)
              }
            }
        }
    });

    // Bind control and chart in Dashboard
    dash.bind(control, chart);

    // Draw dashboard using Dataview as source
    dash.draw(view);
  },
  packages: ['controls', 'corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-csv/0.71/jquery.csv-0.71.min.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard">
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
  <div id="control_div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay! Yes, it works but it is very slow to redraw when I use the actual data set imported from a CSV file which is much larger (1400+ rows x 30 columns). I'll have to perform some tests to see what causes this. I suspect the getColumnRange to set the vAxis.viewWindow or the numerous ticks being redrawn every time I move the range filter trackbars.

Also, I can no longer set the columns I want to see using `view.setColumns( [0,1,5,9,13,17,21,25,29]);` as I did before. When I do I get the "The filter cannot operate on a column of type string" error message again...

Comment: i'm thinking that's why the above answer uses a calculated column in place of `0` -- as for being slow, that's the nature of client-side processing, more data requires more time...

Comment: Was able to accelerate things substantially by removing the `vAxis` `viewWindow` resizing and associated `view.getColumnRange`. I also got rid of the points in the linechart as their density was too high masking all the rest. Now I only need to find a way to choose which columns I want visible from the original CSV data set. Thanks WhiteHat!