# google charts controlwrapper

Tags: google-visualization, controls, wrapper

I want to change the height of a control but it won't work.

This is what i tried so far:

```
   var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
        containerId: 'control_div',
        height: 55,   //placing it here is not working
        options: {
            filterColumnIndex: 0,
            height: 55, //neither does it here
            ui: {
              labelStacking: 'vertical',
              chartType: 'LineChart',
              snapToData: true,
              height: 55, //or here
            },
        }
    });
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be here --> `options.ui.chartOptions.height`

```
options: {
  ui: {
    chartOptions: {
      height: 55
    }
  }
}
```

`ui` is for the control, `chartOptions` for the chart it displays

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38573743/5090771) includes a working example...